# Warning message "Function components cannot be given refs" when using an own child coponent with Dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

When creating an own child function component and use it within `<Dropzone>...</Dropzone>`, I see the following warning message, inside the console:

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Dropzone`.
    at MyContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35421:23
    at header
    at div
    at App
```

My code looks like that:

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

export const MyContainer = ({...other}) => (
    <div {...other}/>
);

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p data-testid="projectNameInput">
          Hello World
        </p>

        <Dropzone onDrop={acceptedFiles => console.log(acceptedFiles)}>
            {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
                <MyContainer {...getRootProps()}>

                    <section>
                        <div>
                            <input {...getInputProps()} />
                            <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                </MyContainer>
            )}
        </Dropzone>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Everything seems to work as expected with the Dropzone and the message disappears, when I don't use `{...getRootProps()}` as attribute-list of `MyContainer`.

Of course I have checked the react documentation about `forwardRef` (https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) and searched for an explanation of this issue. However all explanations do not really fit to my case, because I don't use any reference here at all. At least I don't see the usage of a reference.

Is this an issue of `react-dropzone` or do I use the dropzone wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same warning a while back and found that when you call `getRootProps` it returns several different props, one of them is `ref`:

```js
const { ref, ...rest } = getRootProps();
```

So you are actually using `ref` even though it is not obvious. If you want to use Dropzone on your custom component (`MyContainer` in your case), you have to add [Ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) on `MyContainer`:

```js
const MyContainer = React.forwardRef(ref, {...other}) => (
    <div ref={ref} {...other}/>
);
```

**OR**

You can extract the `ref` value and pass it as a custom prop:

```js
// MyContainer
export const MyContainer = ({ innerRef, ...other}) => ( // make component accept prop innerRef which will be passed to the div's ref prop
  <div ref={innerRef} {...other}/>
);


// App (omitted code before and after)
<Dropzone onDrop={acceptedFiles => console.log(acceptedFiles)}>
  {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => {
    const { ref, ...rootProps } = getRootProps(); // extract ref
    return (
      <MyContainer innerRef={ref} {...rootProps}> // pass ref via custom prop innerRef
        <section>
          <div>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </MyContainer>
    );
  }}
</Dropzone>
```

Hope it helps!